# Unable to expose some ports for NodeJS multi-process servers on Dockerfile

Tags: node.js, server, dockerfile

My goal is to create a Docker image, based on NODE image. Image is supposed to contain several NodeJs servers, running on different ports and expose their endpoints externally.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:14
WORKDIR /app
RUN mkdir webapp2
RUN mkdir webapp2/be
RUN mkdir webapp2/fe

RUN npm install -g http-server && \
npm install -g newman webpack babel figlet

RUN npm install -g express react vue angular typescript
    
# Copy the application code
COPY /pages/* .
COPY index.html .
COPY welcome.js 
COPY webapp2/be/* ./webapp2/be/

EXPOSE 8080 8090 8091 8092 8093 8094 8095

CMD ["node", "welcome.js"]
```

Script welcome.js is responsible for running 2 servers: http-server to serve standard html pages and web-application webpage2 in the background.

```
const http = require('http');
const { exec } = require('child_process');

function startProcess(command) {
  const process = exec(command);

  process.stdout.on('data', data => {
    console.log(data.toString());
  });

  process.on('error', err => {
    console.error(`Error starting process with command '${command}':`, err);
  });

  return process;
}

const webapp2Process = startProcess('node webapp2/be/controller.js > /var/webapp2.log 2>&1 &');
const serverProcess = startProcess('http-server');

// Gracefully stop the processes on program termination
process.on('SIGINT', () => {
  const processes = [serverProcess, , webapp2Process];

  processes.forEach(app => app.kill());
  process.exit();
});
```

As you can see, webapp2Process is ran in the background (thanks to terminating &), and http-server is ran directly.

Code for webapp2:

```
const http = require('http');
const { info } = require('./logic.js');

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
    
    if (req.method === 'GET' && req.url === '/') {
            res.statusCode = 200;
            res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
            res.end(info());
    } 
});

server.listen(8091, 'localhost', () => {
  console.log('Server running at http://localhost:8091/');
});
```

Current status:
Webpages are easily accessible via browser in host system
Webapp2 cannot be accessed via browser in host system -> http://localhost:8091/   returns 404

But, when I connect to Linux terminal, and try curl http://localhost:8091 , the webapp2 return info.

I tried to change the line
server.listen(8091, 'localhost', () => {
to
server.listen(8091, '0.0.0.0', () => {

But no effect.

Comment: Can you make a public git repository with an example of the problem? I tried creating the structure here but it missing some parts

Comment: Sure. Dockerfile: https://github.com/kdrzazga/dockerfiles/blob/NodeJSgame2/jssrv/Dockerfile

Comment: Whole repo (it contains 'projects' for 3 docker images): https://github.com/kdrzazga/dockerfiles/tree/NodeJSgame2

Comment: Pls use branch NodeJSgame2  for current version.

Answer (score 0):

Only exposing is not enough you should also map the host:container ports in the docker run command for example: (image name is `jsgame`)

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 -p 8090:8090 -p 8091:8091 -p 8092:8092 -p 8093:8093 -p 8094:8094 -p 8095:8095 jsgame
```

To make things easier you can use [docker compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/gettingstarted/)

Also you will need to change the servers to not have `'localhost'` and look like this:

```
server.listen(8091, () => {
    console.log('Server running at http://localhost:8091/');
});
```

Otherwise you would get ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE (i am not a docker expert so not totally sure why this is needed)

Comment: Hey. I had done the mapping and ran the image with your command before :)  Besides, port 8080 has been available from external browser, others have not.

Comment: Strange, here it is working... Using Windows i was able to access all apps through the browser, and in docker desktop all ports are mapped: https://prnt.sc/Ruz6LClhUhW-

Comment: I also did a test, created a Ubuntu vm on Azure, copied the `jssrv` folder, built the image there, and runned `sudo docker run -p 80:8091 jsgame` and i was able to access by the  IP

Comment: 8080 is exposed but  8091 is not  https://file.io/PEYcJ8YbFZAl

Comment: File was delete,any chance you have other services running on these ports in host machine?